# Is ribosome denser and smaller than nucleus. Also sone relations in centrifugation related to size and density

Tags: cell-biology, organelle, centrifugation

I want to know that if ribosomes are denser than nucleus. If so, then they should settle at the bottom of tube in centrifugation (following a density gradient) before the nucleus.

Secondly, if ribosomes are smaller than nuclei than they should settle after the nucleus (which they do) but they should also have a smaller Svedberg value (I don't know whether they do or not).

More simply, I want to know whether density or size is responsible for their sedimentation after the nucleus.

I also want to know the relationship between size and Svedberg value of organelles in general.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the higher speeds necessary to collect ribosomes by ultracentrifugation are likely to disrupt the nucleus. See for example [this extract from a well known textbook](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26936/):

> This treatment separates cell components by size and density: in general, the largest units experience the largest centrifugal force and move the most rapidly. **At relatively low speed, large components such as nuclei sediment to form a pellet at the bottom of the centrifuge tube**; at slightly higher speed, a pellet of mitochondria is deposited; and **at even higher speeds and with longer periods of centrifugation, first the small closed vesicles and then the ribosomes can be collected** (Figure 8-8). All of these fractions are impure, but many of the contaminants can be removed by resuspending the pellet and repeating the centrifugation procedure several times.

See the image they reference, which shows that the supernatant from spinning out nuclei will then yield ribosomes upon subsequent spins:

[image]

Ribosomes are much smaller! Recall that [Svedberg units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svedberg) are indirect measures of size. I am not sure that many of the large organelles have Svedberg values per se. Even the ribosome falls apart into subunits upon ultracentrifugation after all, it doesn't really have a singular S value I don't think?